# Why is the return undefined when the recursion hits in this function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

When recursion hits undefined is returned. When recursion doesn't hit the proper result is returned.

I appreciate your wisdom.

This was the prompt on the mutate method.

mutate() is responsible for randomly selecting a base in the object’s dna property
and changing the current base to a different base.
Then .mutate() will return the object’s dna.

For example, if the randomly selected base is the 1st base and it is 'A',
the base must be changed to 'T', 'C', or 'G'. But it cannot be 'A' again

```
// Returns a random DNA base
const returnRandBase = () => {
    const dnaBases = ['A', 'T', 'C', 'G']
    return dnaBases[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)] 
  }
  
  // Returns a random single strand of DNA containing 15 bases
  const mockUpStrand = () => {
    const newStrand = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      newStrand.push(returnRandBase())
    }
    return newStrand
  }
  
  const pAequorFactory = (specimenNum,dna) => {
    return {
      spicimenNum: specimenNum,
      dna: dna,
      mutate() {
        const selectRandBase = this.dna[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.dna.length)];
        const returnRandBaseCall = returnRandBase();
        if(selectRandBase === returnRandBaseCall) {
          console.log("recursion hits");
          this.mutate()
        } else {
          const tempIndex = this.dna.indexOf(selectRandBase);
          this.dna[tempIndex] = returnRandBaseCall
          return this.dna[tempIndex]
        }
      },
    }
  }
 

  
  console.log(pAequorFactory(1,mockUpStrand()).mutate());
```

Comment: Did you check whether your function returns data in **all** cases? As far as I see, you don't do that in the branch where `console.log`  is used

Comment: Thank you, Nico. By all cases do you mean outside of calling the mutant method? If so, I have checked that and all seems to work. If by all cases you mean when the recursion in the if statement doesn't hits then yes. When I console.log the result that is the exact same as the return statement after the recursion hits right above the return statement I get the right result but the return remains undefined.

Comment: What Nico mean is: `this.mutate()` needs to be `return this.mutate()`.

Comment: There is a line that just says `this.mutate()` where you comment "recursion hits". You're never using the result it returns and when the if ends you end up in the en of the function where there always is an invisible "return undefined" in JavaScript. For the other case you return a value so it ONLY works if you hit it on the first round. A return only returns the the first callee and you then have to return that again if that is the final result.